# gdb shared libraries no debugging information

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, sigfpe

i try to debug a program for find to floating point exception location on beaglebone black debian i installed libc6 and libc6-dbg but still

```
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0xb6fda7c0  0xb6ff32b0  Yes (*)     /lib/ld-linux.so.3
0xb6f24200  0xb6f8af00  Yes (*)     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libm.so.6
0xb6f06668  0xb6f17e74  Yes (*)     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libgcc_s.so.1
0xb6dd44a0  0xb6eca348  Yes (*)     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc.so.6
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
```

seems like this.

and my debug directory is:
The directory where separate debug symbols are searched for is "/usr/lib/debug"

floating point exception appear like this

Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0xb6de9a98 in raise () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc.so.6

Comment: Use `bt` command to see where your code throws exception.

Comment: it said not stack. when i remote debug with eclipse when exception thrown just shows assembly and No source available for "0xb6de9a98"

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using GDB with remote debugging, possibly on an x86 host.

> i installed libc6 and libc6-dbg

You need to install `libc6-dbg` for the `arm` (matching your arm target `libc` build). Installing `libc6-dbg` for *host* does you no good.

Comment: i already downloaded libc6-dbg:i386 actually i try to find exception location but i cant

Comment: @OnurÖztürk `libc6-dbg:i386` is *not* what you want. You want the `arm` one.